# JSP, import css,js,images

Tags: java, css, jsp, spring-mvc

I have Spring MVC application with a bunch of *.css, *.js and *.png files currently placed in the ***src/main/java/resources/*** directory.
I read through the Spring Docs and some Tutorials on how to load these files for my templates using the ResourceHandlerRegistry class, but it doesn't work for me.

***My WebConfig (that extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter):***

```js
package by.vk.arteziowebapp.configuration.webConfiguration;

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * The WebConfig.class.
 * Purpose: Web configuration.
 *
 * @author Vadzim Kavalkou
 * @version 1.0 22/07/2016
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"by.vk.arteziowebapp.web", "by.vk.arteziowebapp.configuration.*"})
@PropertySource("classpath:i18n")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * Gets viewResolver with properties.
     *
     * @return viewResolver.
     */
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        viewResolver.setViewClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.class);
        /*Set whether to make all Spring beans in the application context accessible
         as request attributes, through lazy checking once an attribute gets accessed.*/
        viewResolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the path to css,image and js files.
     *
     * @param registry
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/")
                .setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

    /**
     * DispatcherServlet forwards requests for static resources to the servlet container’s default servlet
     * and not tries to handle them itself.
     *
     * @param configurer .
     */
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    /**
     * Gets messageSource with locales description.
     *
     * @return messageSource.
     */
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:i18n/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    /**
     * Gets LocaleResolver object with locale's properties.
     *
     * @return resolver.
     */
    @Bean(name = "localeResolver")
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en"));
        resolver.setCookieName("localCookie");
        resolver.setCookieMaxAge(3600);
        return resolver;
    }

    /**
     * Sets LocaleInterceptors parameters.
     *
     * @param registry
     */
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("locale");
        registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    }
}
```

***My index.jsp: (src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/)***

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:url value="/index?locale=ru" var="localeRU"/>
<c:url value="/index?locale=en" var="localeEN"/>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title><spring:message code="label.titleIndex"/></title>

    <spring:url value="/resources/css/style.css" var="css"/>
    <spring:url value="/resources/js/script.js" var="js"/>
    <spring:url value="/resources/js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js" var="jq"/>
    <spring:url value="/resources/images/vk.png" var="vk"/>
    <spring:url value="/resources/images/vk-mouseover.png" var="vkMouseOver"/>

    <link href="${css}" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>

<body>

<c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
    <p>
        <spring:message code="label.logoutMessage"/>
    </p>
</c:if>

<div id="locales"><a href="${localeRU}">RU</a> | <a href="${localeEN}">EN</a></div>

<form:form action='/result' method='get' id="loginForm">

    <h1><spring:message code="label.titleIndex"/></h1>

    <fieldset id="inputs">
        <input id="email" type='text' placeholder="<spring:message code="label.email"/>"/>
        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="<spring:message code="label.password"/>"/>
    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.loginButton"/>"/>

    <input type="hidden"
           name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
           value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form:form>

<footer id="footer">
    <div id="footer-info">&copy VK, 2015-</div>
    <div id="image-ref">
        <a href="http://vk.com/"><img id="vk-image" src="${vk}"></a>
    </div>
</footer>

<script src="${js}" rel="script"/>
<script src="${jq}" rel="script"/>

</body>

</html>
```

Thank you,mates!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the files from src/main/java/resources to  src/main/resources
and remove the "/resources" part in the spring config, e.g.

```
 <spring:url value="/css/style.css" var="css"/>
```

Maven will place files in the resources directory in the root of the classpass and not into a /resources folder in the root of the classpath.

Comment: I checked my *.war file , and I didnt find here resources folder. There is only web-inf and meta-inf...

Comment: the should not be a resources folder in the war. These files should be in the toplevel folder of the war. Please move the css, js and images directories to the webapp folder. Then it should work.